Simple Update Record screen flow
I have set up a screen flow to update a checkbox on the QuoteLineItem record to true. A button on the record starts the screen flow.
The flow is simple: update the record matching {!recordId} for the field to be true.  The debug works fine.  The flow in action, though, doesn't show the new field value without a screen refresh.  I updated the button URL to include a return and save, but I still have the cache(?) issue.
/flow/QLI_Make_Primary?recordId={!QuoteLineItem.Id}&retURL=/{!QuoteLineItem.Id}&save=1
Any suggestions on what to change please?

the button is on a QuoteLineItem? &save=1 shouldn't be necessary. See doc
